# Error fetching registered user data - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Friends, I'm trying to do tests with payment. I need to get the address of the logged in user to register the payment. I have this method:

```cs
transaction.Shipping = new Shipping
    {
        Name = cliente.Name,
        Fee = Mascara.ConverterValorPagarMe(fee),
        Expedited = false,
        AddressApi = new AddressApi()
        {
            Country = "br",
            State = person.address.State,
            City = person.address.City,
            Neighborhood = person.address.Neighborhood,
            Street = person.address.Street,
            StreetNumber = person.address.StreetNumber,
            Zipcode = person.address.Zipcode

        }
    };
```

I have a table of people and an address table. I can register the user correctly, but I get an error when trying to get the address to make the payment.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> LojaVirtual.Models.person.address.get retornou null.

The line

```
Name = cliente.Name
```

returns the user name, but

```
State = person.address.State
```

returns `null`.

My method for obtaining user information is as follows:

```cs
public person GetPerson()
{
    // Deserializar
    if ( _sessao.Existe(Key)) 
    {
        string personJSONString = _sessao.Consult(Key);            
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<person>(personJSONString);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT

---

```
public string Consult(string Key)
{
    return _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(Key);
}
```

I appreciate any comments.

Comment: Post your Json.

Comment: The code of _sessao.Consult(Key); would be interesting.

Comment: I did a code update!